# mod_perl causing Apache Segmentation fault - why?

Tags: apache, mod-perl

My mod_perl appears to cause a segmentation fault in my Apache. 'httpd -X' simply gives 'Segmentation Fault' and my server does not start.

I am using Apache 2.2.22, mod_perl 2.0.5, CentOS 5.7 x86_64. I built mod_perl and Apache together from source with the following command:

> perl5.12.4 Makefile.PL MP_USE_STATIC=1 MP_AP_PREFIX=/usr/local/src/httpd-2.2.22     MP_AP_CONFIGURE="--with-mpm=prefork --enable-rewrite"

What I have tried so far:

1. Point httpd.conf to my Catalyst application. Result: Apache dies with 'Segmentation fault'.
2. Point httpd.conf to a simple application created with catalyst.pl. Apache dies with 'Segmentation fault'.
3. Point httpd.conf to a static site. Result: Apache starts fine and serves the website.

I tried the following:

> gdb -c /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd
>
> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>
> 0x00002aaab0db0270 in ?? ()
>
> (gdb) bt
>
> #0  0x00002aaab0db0270 in ?? ()
>
> #1  0x00000000004c9d24 in Perl_newUNOP ()
>
> #2  0x00000000004fb6a6 in Perl_yyparse ()
>
> #3  0x0000000000557c57 in S_doeval ()
>
> #4  0x0000000000559546 in Perl_pp_require ()
>
> #5  0x0000000000528bae in Perl_runops_standard ()
>
> #6  0x00000000004d5d2f in Perl_eval_sv ()
>
> #7  0x0000000000478425 in modperl_require_module ()
>
> #8  0x0000000000472283 in modperl_boot ()
>
> #9  0x00000000005529cc in Perl_leave_scope ()
>
> #10 0x00000000004d87eb in S_parse_body ()
>
> #11 0x00000000004d927c in perl_parse ()
>
> #12 0x0000000000471d2a in modperl_startup ()
>
> #13 0x0000000000471cbc in modperl_startup ()
>
> #14 0x000000000047202e in modperl_init ()
>
> #15 0x000000000047215f in modperl_hook_init ()
>
> #16 0x00000000004737bb in modperl_cmd_perldo ()
>
> #17 0x000000000046432b in invoke_cmd (cmd=0x5b9880, parms=0x7fffffffe770, 
>   mconfig=0x844728, args=0x89b7d8 "use lib qw( /usr/local/apache2/virtualhosts/api.nwwi.nl
>   /httpdocs/lib/ );\n") at config.c:757
>
> #18 0x0000000000465865 in ap_walk_config_sub (current=0x89b828, parms=0x7fffffffe770, section_vector=0x830c18) at config.c:1163
>
> #19 0x0000000000465914 in ap_walk_config (current=0x89b828, parms=0x7fffffffe770, section_vector=0x830c18) at config.c:1196
>
> #20 0x0000000000466cb9 in ap_process_config_tree (s=0x82de10, conftree=0x86fcb0, p=0x822138, ptemp=0x82a178) at config.c:1765
>
> #21 0x0000000000449512 in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe9e8) at main.c:723

I have no idea how to read and interpret this. Can somebody help and point me in a direction to further troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received the following response from Dave Hodgkinson on the mod_perl mailing list:

> #17 0x000000000046432b in invoke_cmd (cmd=0x5b9880,
>
> ```
> parms=0x7fffffffe770, mconfig=0x844728, args=0x89b7d8 "use lib qw(
> ```
>
> /usr/local/apache2/virtualhosts/api.nwwi.nl /httpdocs/lib/ );\n") at
>
> ```
> config.c:757
> ```
>
> **This appears to be what it's trying to do. Take that directive
>   out and see what happens?**

After some experimentation I changed part of the Apache configuration from

```
PerlSwitches -I/srv/www/example.com/application/lib/

<Perl>
    use lib qw( /srv/www/example.com/application/lib/ );
</Perl>

PerlModule application
```

to

```
<Perl>
    use lib qw( /srv/www/example.com/application/lib/ );
</Perl>
```

and this fixed my issue.